# String operations in python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, filter

I have a variable **mystr** (string type)
which holds the following data :

> zxoxcndsabcaa88912, (Used Disc Space,Requests per Minute,OS Memory
>   Usage,Busy Threads,Disk I/O,Heap Memory Usage,CPU Load,Average
>   Response
>   Time,AccessTokenCount,RequestsCountPerMin,AverageResponseTimePerMin,CurrentBusyThreads,CurrentUsedMemory,ActiveClientRegistrationThreads,BorrowedConnectionsCount,ClientCount,RefreshTokenCount,FailedAccountTerminations,Error500CountMin,AuthorizationCodeCount)zxoxcndsabcaa900342,
>   (Used Disc Space,Requests per Minute,OS Memory Usage,Busy Threads,Disk
>   I/O,Heap Memory Usage,CPU Load,Average Response
>   Time,AccessTokenCount,RequestsCountPerMin,AverageResponseTimePerMin,CurrentBusyThreads,CurrentUsedMemory,ActiveClientRegistrationThreads,BorrowedConnectionsCount,ClientCount,RefreshTokenCount,FailedAccountTerminations,Error500CountMin,AuthorizationCodeCount)

From this I am filtering if Busy Threads are present then it should go for a system exit if not then it should execute the rest part of code.

Here is my code:

```
print type(mystr)
if 'Busy Threads' in mystr:
   print 'Busy threads is present'
   sys.exit(1)
else:
   print 'Busy threads not present'
```

check()

But what I am facing problem here is I am having one more string **CurrentBusyThreads** in the result of mystr apart from **Busy Threads** so even if the **Busy Threads** are not present it takes **CurrentBusyThreads** and executes the rest part which is not expected.

any other way to exactly filter out **Busy Threads** only

Comment: 'BusyThreads' will not match 'Busy Threads' -- there's a space in one of them.

Comment: can you give a clear explaination on what you want to achieve i am getting on a small part from the question

Comment: Assuming you mistakenly put the space in between `Busy` and `Threads` and it is in fact `BusyThreads`, then another cheap way to achieve what you want would be to remove the `CurrentBusyThreads` beforehand with the `mystr.replace` method. Doesnt work in case any other kinds of BuysThreads start appearing, but gets the job done otherwise.

Comment: @jonatan so is there any way to match with the space part ?

Comment: @Alex include the space if it's supposed to match that.  Or use two conditions (the `or` operator can be used to combine them)

Comment: @Jeronimo I have not mistakenly put it is the way it is "Busy Threads" with a space.
and if you notice I am matching in the if filter as same thing Busy Threads.

Comment: @jonatan I have already used the space while matching in "if filter"
do you mean I should do this >> if 'Busy Threads' or BusyThreads in mystr:

Comment: @Alex you would need to compare both to mystr, your suggestion in your last comment was ('Busy Threads') or ('BusyThreads' in mystr) -- note how the first one isn't compared to anything. You would need to make TWO comparisons, and then check if EITHER comparison resulted in a match.

Comment: @jonatan done but its not working still it takes **Current Busy Threads** and prints "Busy threads is present"  although I have removed "Busy Thread" from mystr output.

Comment: @Alex then you might need to filter out "Current Busy Threads" first

Comment: @Alex you could split the string on comma and check each one individually with ==

Comment: i am not getting it can you pate it what you have tried and worked ? it would be great thanks in advance

Comment: "Busy Threads" does **not** match "CurrentBusyThreads" if checked for with the `in`operator. Note that "Busy Threads" appears more than once in your string. Maybe that's where you went wrong? You can also use `mystr.index("Busy Threads")` to debug, which will give you the exact position. I highly recommend using an interactive Python console like [IPython qtconsole](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/qtconsole.html) when tinkering around with such stuff.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use regex to make rules about string you want to find.

You should use 
re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)

Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

For your problem:

```
pattern = 'Busy\s+Threads'
if re.search(pattern, mystr):
    #do soemhting
```

link to doc:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of regex expression can you help with it

Comment: You wanna use re.serch. You have to read more about it Yourself, how to use, what is  pattern, etc. With regular expression  you can inclulde or exclude any patterns you wanna search for in a string.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17582493)

Comment: Edited my post. My asnwer wasn't link only, in link he could find more about it. Also i don't think it is very likely official python documentation page will change.

Comment: @YPCrumble Thanks for the review.

Comment: @ŁukaszSzczesiak It worked perfectly and thanks for giving the link above will learn more about regex.